# How to measure LAB values with impixelinfo

Tags: matlab, image-processing, colors

I am trying to measure specific sections of my image in the LAB colour space with impixelinfo. I expect the output parameters to show values in [L* A* B*] values at the bottom of the screen.

I've tried something similar in RGB and HSV colour spaces before, but trying out this function with LAB images gives me weird results, as (linked) below.

The function does give me values as I hover my mouse over the image, but they are in RGB and each component will only give me either a 1.00 or a 0.00. I expected something like:

Pixel info:(1947,563) [55.28 28.45 -65.62] or something.

What am I doing wrong???

```
rgbImage = imread(file);

% Convert image from RGB colorspace to lab color space.
    cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
    lab_Image = applycform(im2double(rgbImage),cform);

figure, imshow(lab_Image); 
impixelinfo;
```

Image Link http://postimg.org/image/y5u83mvxf/

[image: Problem Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scaling. Weird image? Blank image? Values which are all zero or one? The answer is always scaling.

`im2double` will scale your input image between 0 and 1, which is the required range for images of type double in MATLAB (at least, if you want anything to work like you expect it to).  However, after conversion to LAB the values are no longer in this range.

`imshow` doesn't know what to do with an (it presumes) RGB image which contains doubles which are outside the normal range. Therefore it does what MATLAB image functions always do in these situations - it clips the data without any sort of error or warning. Anything less than zero becomes a zero, anything greater than one becomes one. You see a very limited color palette in your image, not a binary black and white image, because your image is n x m x 3 not just 2D.

What you can do depends on what you want to do (why are you using `impixelinfo`), but if you just want to explore your image a bit then one option is to plot the three layers separately - `impixelinfo` works fine in these cases, and you'll see it return the exact numbers:

```
figure
% use [] to force proper display scaling, too
subplot(2,2,1); imshow(lab_image(:,:,1),[]);
subplot(2,2,2); imshow(lab_image(:,:,2),[]);
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(lab_image(:,:,3),[]);
impixelinfo;
```

Obviously, though, that's a bit awkward.

Another option would be to not use `impixelinfo` at all, as you won't ever get `imshow` to show your LAB image correctly anyway. Use the original RGB image for display, then use some sort of interactive ROI method such as `imfreehand` to select an area of interest.  Use that as a mask to tell you what the equivalent LAB values are.

If you haven't used the ROI methods in MATLAB before, start here:
http://uk.mathworks.com/help/images/roi-based-processing.html

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply; but it doesn't seem to work.  I get the error below:                                                                                                                                                     ??? Maximum recursion limit of 500 reached. Use set(0,'RecursionLimit',N)
to change the limit. Be aware that exceeding your available stack space can
crash MATLAB and/or your computer.

Comment: `rgbImage = imread(file);

% Convert image from RGB colorspace to lab color space.
    cform = makecform('srgb2lab');
    lab_Image = applycform(im2double(rgbImage),cform);

    
figure
% use [] to force proper display scaling, too
subplot(2,2,1); imshow(lab_Image(:,:,1),[]);
subplot(2,2,2); imshow(lab_Image(:,:,2),[]);
subplot(2,2,3); imshow(lab_Image(:,:,3),[]);
impixelinfo;`

Comment: I can do freehand ROI, but sometimes the area I want to select is pretty small. So I thought it would be simpler (and more accurate) if I did the impixelinfo way.

Comment: Okay you're completely right. I named the script _impixeinfo.m_. Hah. Thanks! Won't do that again.